# How to load data into salesforce when I've run out of licenses?

Tags: data, upload

I have 10 saleforce.com licenses assigned to Sales Rep. Data admin needs to upload leads to salesforce how can he upload the data as there are only 10 licenses available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a license to be able to upload data. There is no other way.

You could consider temporarily (e.g. outside of office hours) deactivating a Sales Rep license and assigning the license to your data admin. Then after the upload is done, deactivate the data admin and re-activate the Sales Rep.

Alternatively, purchase extra licenses...

Comment: Also, salesforce has cheap licenses that allow limited logins per month or with other limits that may be suitable for the occasional user.

Comment: What if I don't wan't to deactivate the sales rep and also have no option to by new license is there a way that the data can be uploaded to salesforce.

Comment: As stated, you need a license to be able to upload data. There is no other way. That is also the key to the entire sfdc security and audit model. Any changes to data can only be done by a logged in user that has the correct authorization.

Answer (score 2):

There are a [multitude of tools you can use](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=import_which_data_import_tool.htm), but you may want to consider the [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) or the [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_import_wizard.htm&language=en_US). It would be a great idea to read up on the [best practices of data loading](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/best_practices_with_any_data_loader.htm) before progressing.

As far as how you import them, just use the Admin's login (they should have a license associated with them as well). You must have an activate user actually load the data. If needed, you may need to purchase additional licenses.